# CSS image slider doesn't slide

Tags: html, css, slideshow, css-animations

I'm building an image slider containing 5 images which are displayed on the top of my webpage. The first image shows up when I test it online. But it isn't animating. Who can help me :)

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
        <figure>
            <img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/austin-fireworks.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/taj-mahal.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/ibiza.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/ankor-wat.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/austin-fireworks.jpg" alt="">
        </figure>
</div>
```

And this my CSS:

```
div#slider { 
display: block;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow:         0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);}


div#slider figure img { 
    width: 20%; 
}
div#slider figure { 
    position: relative;
    width: 500%;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    -webkit-animation: 30s slidy infinite;
    -moz-animation: 30s slidy infinite;
    animation: 30s slidy infinite;
}



div#slider .title{
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;    
    color:white;
    font-size: 11pt;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 90%;
}

@keyframes slidy {
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}
```

Why doesn't the images slide to the left? I want to make it work on iOS and Android devices.

Comment: [**It works fine for me**](http://jsfiddle.net/98nQq/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct but the @keyframes doesn't work in all browsers so I added the -webkit-keyframes and it is working for me.

```
@-webkit-keyframes slidy /* Safari and Chrome */
{
    20% { left: 0%; }
    25% { left: -100%; }
    45% { left: -100%; }
    50% { left: -200%; }
    70% { left: -200%; }
    75% { left: -300%; }
    95% { left: -300%; }
    100% { left: -400%; }
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RX3jN/

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the entire javascript that handles the effects and transitions. I will suggest you to read a little bit more about it on sites like http://wowslider.com/index.html#overview

In general terms you define the HTML and the CSS but also some JS (javascript is needed to make it work) you can use an existing framework (a group of functions to make a task easier) or do it by hand (writing all the needed code).